# How to fetch instances of instance groups for a managed instance group with multi-zone configuration

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I recently started using managed instance group with multi zone configuration. When i use GCE api to fetch instances for this instance groups zone is a required parameter. For a managed instance group with instances in multiple zone instance group does not belong to one zone. how do i fetch instances in this case?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already or what code is currently working for you?

Answer (score 2):

What API or gcloud command are you using to list the instances? I guess you are using the [instanceGroups.listInstances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instanceGroups/listInstances) API, but for regional instance group, you need to use [regionInstanceGroupManagers.listManagedInstances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/regionInstanceGroupManagers/listManagedInstances), or the corresponding gcloud command:

`$ gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed list-instances instance-group-1 --region us-central1
NAME                   ZONE           STATUS   ACTION  LAST_ERROR
instance-group-1-mk4j  us-central1-b  RUNNING  NONE
instance-group-1-xnyk  us-central1-c  RUNNING  NONE
instance-group-1-g23r  us-central1-f  RUNNING  NONE`

Note that this feature is still in beta.

Comment: um, it seems like you are basically saying "you can not get a list of regional instance groups".      as you are instead showing how to list instances in that group.